# I don't understand how to add arguments to a rake task. (Excerpt from the documentation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm trying to create a custom rake task that takes in two arguments and uses them in my code.

I'm looking at the rails documentation and I see this excerpt for running a rails task with an argument:

```
task :task_name, [:arg_1] => [:pre_1, :pre_2] do |t, args|
  # You can use args from here
end
```

The rake task can then be invoked like this:

```
bin/rake "task_name[value 1]"
```

However, this is way too vague for me. The rails documentation fails to give a concrete example of a rake task with an argument.

For example, I'm looking at this code and I'm thinking what does `bin/rake "task_name[value 1]"` do? What is `[:pre1, :pre2]`?

Additionally, I've found some other fantastic links that do things a little bit differently. Here are the links.

[Thoughtbot version](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-use-arguments-in-a-rake-task)

In the thoughtbot version that have this example

```
 task :send, [:username] => [:environment] do |t, args|
   Tweet.send(args[:username])
 end
```

What is the `[:username => [:environment]`? its different than the official rails docs.

Here is another:
[4 ways to write rake tasks with arguments](http://cobwwweb.com/4-ways-to-pass-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

I've also looked at the officail optparser documentation and that too has a different way of making it work.

All I want is for this example code that I have to work on my `.rake` file:

```
require 'optparse' 
task :add do 
  options = {}
  OptionParser.new do |opts| 
    opts.banner = "Usage: rake add" 
    opts.on("-o", "--one ARGV", Integer) { |one| options[:one] = one } 
    opts.on("-t", "--two ARGV", Integer) { |two| options[:two] = two } 
  end.parse! 
  puts options[:one].to_i + options[:two].to_i
end
```

The code fails because of `invalid option: -o`. I just want to make this work so I can move on. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of my rake tasks with arguments:

```
namespace :admin do
  task :create_user, [:user_email, :user_password, :is_superadmin] => :environment do |t, args|
    email = args[:email]
    password = args[:password]
    is_superadmin = args[:is_superadmin]
    ... lots of fun code ...
  end
end
```

and I invoke this task like this:

```
rake admin:create_user['admin@example.com','password',true]
```

#### EDIT

To pass flags in you can do something like this:

```
task :test_task do |t, args|
  options = {a: nil, b: nil}
  OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.banner = "Usage: admin:test_task [options]"
      opts.on("--a", "-A", "Adds a") do |a|
        options[:a] = true
      end   
      opts.on("--b", "-B", "Adds b") do |b|
        options[:b] = true
      end   
    end.parse!

  puts options.inspect
end
```

And examples of invoking it:

```
rake admin:test_task -A -B
rake admin:test_task -A
rake admin:test_task -B
```

Comment: Thanks for the response james. Would you happen to know how to add flags to a rake task. That is really what I'm trying to go for with this question.